# OpenCV program doesnt start the camera

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-electric, uvc-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I recently installed ROS Electric, and now I'm trying to use OpenCV with it, I followed certain tutorials as this one [Working with ROS and OpenCV](http://siddhantahuja.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/working-with-ros-and-opencv-draft/) (no sure if anyone else tried this too) ... Thing is, my built-in camera worked fine when i launch this .launch program:

(Refer to the part **Test the launch script** in the link above)

It does turn on, and writing this in terminal
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw
I can see the image, but when I write my .cpp program for using OpenCV and I run it (refer to the part **Write the code for image processing**), my camera doesn't turn on, it doesnt show an error or anything it just stays there ... I have tried w another webcams and same thing happened. Does anyone have a clue why isn't running

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32024/opencv-program-doesnt-start-the-camera/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2012-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You still have to run uvc_cam node.

The code you are talking about uses image transport in another node to grab the images from the ucv_cam node and process them. These are two different nodes working together ... one to grab images from your camera and one to process them.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1